# Separating Digits in Int into Separate Ints

Tags: c++, performance, int, runtime, digits

Ideally, I would like to take an int of say... 13647 and split it like so:

The first new variable (int) is the first digit.
The second is the first two digits.
The third is the first three digits...
and so on and so on.

I'm having trouble figuring out how exactly to do this while maintaining an efficient runtime. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @lubgr as I understand, OP wants 13647 -> 1, 13, 136, 1364, 13647, which the dupe doesnt answer completely

Comment: ...well, actually this is easier than what the dupe is asking for, so maybe the dupe is ok

Comment: take pen and paper, what operations do you need to perform to get 13 from 13647?

Comment: YES once I figured out the formula and how to modulo it made much more sense. You are right it is actually easier then. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int num = 13647;
    char inArr[20];
    itoa(num, inArr, 10);
    int numArr[strlen(inArr)];

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(inArr); i++) {
        numArr[i] = num/pow(10, strlen(inArr) - i - 1);
        printf("num[%d] = %d\n", i, numArr[i]); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
num[0] = 1
num[1] = 13
num[2] = 136
num[3] = 1364
num[4] = 13647
```

Comment: Wow thank you this is definitely more what I am looking for. I have to do quite a few operations to the numbers derived but I am not worried about the code needed to do them so this was very helpful!